# How to set default focus to a textbox angular2 way?

Tags: angular, typescript

Tried html5 autofocus, but not working in internet explorer. Tried solutions using viewchildren/viewchild/elementref inside component, none worked for me. I'm using "@angular/core": "~2.2.3".

Any one please provide me with a working solution for this.

Comment: Could you please add plunkr/fiddle of the same?

Comment: Have you tried `[autofocus]="true"` ?

Comment: *Tried solutions using viewchildren/viewchild/elementref inside component* May we see your attempts? I don't believe this way does not work

Comment: @Pankaj Parker, @ smnbbrv, The following is one way i tried. import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef,ViewChildren,Renderer } from "@angular/core";   @ViewChildren('name') VC: QueryList<ElementRef>; injected Renderer inside constructor.  inside oninit      this._renderer.invokeElementMethod(this.VC.first.nativeElement, 'focus', []);

Comment: @micronyks, Tried that, but not working in ie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the following solution,

### Create a directive

```
 import { Component, NgModule, Directive, ElementRef, Renderer } from    '@angular/core'
 import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'

 @Directive({
   selector: 'form[setFocus]'
 })
 export class SelectFirstInputDirective {

constructor(private _eRef: ElementRef, private _renderer: Renderer) { }

private _getInputElement(nativeElement: any): any {
    if (!nativeElement || !nativeElement.children) return undefined;
    if (!nativeElement.children.length && nativeElement.localName === 'input' && !nativeElement.hidden) return nativeElement;

    let input:any;

    [].slice.call(nativeElement.children).every((c:any) => {
        input = this._getInputElement(c);
        if (input) return false; // break
        return true; // continue!
    });

    return input;
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
    let formChildren = [].slice.call(this._eRef.nativeElement.children);

    formChildren.every((child:any) => {
        let input = this._getInputElement(child);

        if (input) {
            this._renderer.invokeElementMethod(input, 'focus', []);
            return false; // break!
        }
        return true; // continue!
    });
  }
}
```

### Register the directive

```
  @NgModule({
    imports: [
    BrowserModule],
declarations: [
    AppComponent     
    , SelectFirstInputDirective],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

### Use it in the form tag

```
 <form [formGroup]="someForm" (ngSubmit)="someMethod(someForm)" novalidate setFocus>
```

Answer (score -1):

This works for me `[autofocus]="true"` check it out